# Default value is not setting in tkinter radiobutton

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, radio-button

```
from tkinter import *
master=Tk()
class radio:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        methods = [('Name', 1), ('Number', 2), ('Date', 3), ('Area', 4), ('Mountain', 5), ('Country', 6), ('Place', 7)]
        self.v = IntVar()
        self.v.set(1)
        for method, value in methods:
            rad = Radiobutton(root, text=method, variable=self.v, value=value)
            rad.pack()

radio(master)
master.mainloop()
```

This is my code. I was trying to set default position of radio button to value '1'. But when I hover mouse pointer above these radio button all the radio button get selected like in the picture[image]. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't keeping a reference to the `radio` object so the value is getting garbage-collected.

Save a reference and the default value will be set properly:

```
r = radio(master)
```